# Trying to transfer data from sets more efficiently

Tags: java

So this is purely for pleasure, my teacher gave us this in class today and it's not for marks or anything it's pretty much just to see if we can solve it. So we have to write a pretty generic data transfer program. We input from a text file something that looks like:

`(datacenter ID): (document); (document); (document)`;

now he wants us to split, and have the datacenter ID and the documents, so i made a set for each data center and it stores of type document. Now the problem where I'm having is the following. His example was:

`1: A;C;D;E;G;
2: A;C;
3: B;`

Now each one of these datacenters (1,2,3) are supposed to contain all the possible documents i.e. 1: A;B;C;D;E;G; and same for 2: and 3:. now i figured why not just copy them all into one and copy that to the rest. But my teacher said that's not the proper way to design it it'll require to much time and it's not as efficient, he wants this to work for pretty much an infinite number of datacenters and documents.
I have all the split coding and things done I just can't figure out a pattern or algorithm and it's driving me bananas, this is the sample he gave us for how the data should be copied and transfered:

B:3→2
B:3→1
A:2→3
D:1→2
E:1→3
E:3→2
D:2→3
C:1→3
G:1→2
G:2→3
He wants to pretty much divide the tasks evenly i just cant figure out the pattern or how i would do that.. please help

Comment: *"it's pretty much just to see if we can solve it."*  Based on your complete lack of attempt, and lack of a question, I'd guess 'no'.

Comment: well I've managed to do everything else but understand how this pattern works..

Comment: What pattern?  I don't even understand the problem.  You have text file with datacenter -> multiple documents, but every datacenter has to contain all documents, and then something about sets.   ... what?

Comment: Is this some attempt to mirror the data? Like if in the server 1 contains a;b;c all other server must have this three and if in the server 2 has the document d the final should be: 1: a;b;c;d 2: a;b;c;d This is the best I could gues from your explanation

Comment: @JorgeCampos well, I'm impressed you deduced all that from the question. :)  Even so, not really much to go on.